# WooCommerce PayPal Payments user redirection after credit card decline not working

Tags: woocommerce, paypal, paypal-sandbox

i'm testing WooCommerce PayPal Payments with a paypal sandbox account.

When i test credit card payment decline (in particular with insufficient funds rejection trigger https://developer.paypal.com/tools/sandbox/card-testing/#rejection-triggers) after the payment fails the user is not redirected to the thank you page where he can see that the card was declined but is being redirected again to paypal sandbox page to retry the payment **without any failure message being displayed**.

Why is this happening? Shouldn't the user get a card declined notification somewhere?

Comment: Forgot to say: current plugin version is 1.9.5

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue with the help of Woocommerce Paypal Payments forum.

Basically, in 1.9.5 implementation, when the credit card fails the plugin restarts the payment process up to two times then sends you back to the checkout page where is displayed the error.